# How to write a client/server socket program in C to request a hostname IP address?

Tags: c, sockets, ip, server, client

I am making a client/server socket program where the client can send a hostname request and the server returns the IP address of the hostname. I do not know what's wrong but my (get_IP) function seems not to work, even though it returns the hostname correctly on the server side. When I change the buffer size on line 109 to 14 and I request "www.google.com", from the client side, it works fine. I suspect that the problem is caused by the buffer. A little help?

**Server.c**

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define SERVER_PORT   16700 


char *get_IP(char *host)
{
  struct hostent *hent;
  int iplen = 15;
  char *ip = (char *)malloc(iplen+1);

  memset(ip, 0, iplen+1);
  if((hent = gethostbyname(host)) == NULL)
  {
     herror("Can't get IP");
     exit(1);
  }
  if(inet_ntop(AF_INET,(void *)hent->h_addr_list[0], ip, iplen) == NULL)
  {
    perror("Can't resolve the host");
    exit(1);
  }
  return ip;
}

char *host_page(char *ip)
{
  int sockfd = 0, n;
  char buffer[1024];
  struct sockaddr_in host_addr;
  char *page = malloc(1024);

  memset(buffer, '0' ,sizeof(buffer));
  if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP))< 0)
      error("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");


  host_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  host_addr.sin_port = htons(80);
  host_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);

  if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&host_addr, sizeof(host_addr))<0)
     error("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");


  n = write(sockfd,"GET", 3);
  if (n < 0) 
     error("\n ERROR: writing to socket");


  //getting server response
  bzero(buffer,1024);
  n = read(sockfd,buffer,1023);
  if (n < 0) 
     error("\n ERROR: reading from socket");
  strcpy(page, buffer);

  close(sockfd);

 return page;
}


int main(void)
{
  int sockfd, listenfd = 0,connfd = 0, newsockfd, clilen;

  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

  char buffer[1025];  
  int n;  

/* Establishing communication with socket */

  printf("XXXXXX - WELCOME TO PAUL'S PROXY SERVER - XXXXXX \n\n");

  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  printf("Connection established... \n\n");

  memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
  memset(buffer, '0', sizeof(buffer));

  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);  
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)SERVER_PORT);

  bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));

  if(listen(sockfd, 10) == -1)
     error("Failed to listen\n");

/* start communication with client */     

  newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, &clilen);
  if(newsockfd < 0)
     error("ERROR on accept");

  //getting hostname request
  bzero(buffer, 1024);
  n = read(newsockfd, buffer, 14);

  if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR reading from socket");
  printf("client requested IP for: %s \n", buffer);

  char ip[40];

  strcpy (ip, get_IP(buffer));

  char page[2000];  

  strcpy(page, host_page(ip));



  //Sending response to client request
  n = write(newsockfd, page, 1024);

  if(n<0)
     error("ERROR reading from socket");      



  return 0;
}
```

---

**Client.c**

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define SERVER_IP    "129.120.151.94"
#define SERVER_PORT  46700

int main(void)
{
  int sockfd = 0, n;
  char buffer[1024];
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

  memset(buffer, '0' ,sizeof(buffer));
  if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP))< 0)
      error("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");


  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)SERVER_PORT);
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVER_IP);

  if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
     error("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");

  printf("Enter hostname in the form www.host.domain:");
  bzero(buffer,1024);
  fgets(buffer,1023,stdin);
  n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
  if (n < 0) 
     error("\n ERROR: writing to socket");

  printf("\n hostname IP is: ");
  bzero(buffer,1024);
  n = read(sockfd,buffer,1023);
  if (n < 0) 
     error("\n ERROR: reading from socket");
  printf("%s\n",buffer); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add details how it does not work. What errors do you receive?

Comment: When calling fgets() use the full size of the input buffer.   The fgets() function will stop inputting characters when it sees a newline, EOF, of the input buffer only has one char left.  Then fgets() will append a NUL byte to the contents of the input buffer.    Due note that the newline will also be in the input buffer, that newline (if present) needs to be replaced with a NUL byte.

Comment: You can get the IP of a host by calling `gethostbyname()`  using the syntax: `struct hostent *gethostbyname(const char *name);`  Without ever accessing the host.  Similarly, `gethostbyaddr()` will get the host name using the syntax: `struct hostent *gethostbyaddr(const void *addr, socklen_t len, int type);`

Comment: this line: `printf("\n hostname IP is: ");` the following few lines are a total waste as the host IP is already hardcoded into the client source code.

Comment: Everywhere I looked, the code incorrectly deals with null-terminated strings. This topic needs to be studied carefully.

Comment: when calling malloc() and family of functions, the code should always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: why is the server code writing to the socket before calling 'listen()' and 'accept()'?